# visual c# chart not showing all points in X Axis

Tags: c#, charts

I am having some problems painting data in a chart in a form.
I set the `DataBindXY(Arr1,Arr2)`
Where `Arr1` is `DateTime` type and `Arr2` is `Double` type.

When debugging, I can see that both arrays has good values:

```
Chart1.Series[0].Points
Count = 9
    [0]: {{X=44762,4066666667, Y={34, 0}}}
    [1]: {{X=44762,4065972222, Y={55, 0}}}
    [2]: {{X=44762,4065625, Y={33, 0}}}
    [3]: {{X=44762,4065162037, Y={60, 0}}}
    [4]: {{X=44762,4054050926, Y={40, 0}}}
    [5]: {{X=44762,4053935185, Y={40, 0}}}
    [6]: {{X=44762,4053356481, Y={30, 0}}}
    [7]: {{X=44762,4052777778, Y={20, 0}}}
    [8]: {{X=44762,4052314815, Y={10, 0}}}
```

But the chart is painted like this:

[image: Chart image]

Where you can see that only the last timestamp is drawn.

I tried to set

```
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss";
```

and

```
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it!

```
i = 0;
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.CustomLabels.Clear();

foreach (System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPoint pt in Chart1.Series[0].Points)
{
       CustomLabel cLabel1= new CustomLabel(startOffset, endOffset, Arr1[i].ToString(), 0, LabelMarkStyle.None);                    
       Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(cLabel1);
       startOffset += 1;
       endOffset += 1;
       i++;
}
```